# Saving one-to-many by IDs in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I seem to be overlooking a basic Laravel Eloquent functionality.

Using the following (Mongo, using [Jenssegers package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) DB structure & Classes:

```
Owner (id,car_ids)
Car (id)

Class Owner extends Model
{
  public function cars(): HasMany
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
  }
}

Class Car extends Model
{
  public function owner(): BelongsTo
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class);
  }
}
```

One owner can have multiple cars, a car belongs to one owner.

Now, I get a list of existing car ids as input, and want to attach them to an existing owner.
Must I first loop and find the car models by the ids, then use `saveMany` ? Isn’t there an option to directly store the ids?

Answer (score -1):

You should place a `select` tag on your blade like below:

```
<select name="cars[]" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Then, after submitting your form, you can get the car's id and use `saveMany` like below:

```
$owner = Owner::find(1);
$ids = $request->input('cars');
$owner->cars()->saveMany($ids);
```

Comment: Just tried but I get `HasOneOrMany::save(): Argument #1 ($model) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given`.